# Как добавить css стиль к html элементу через js?

Tags: javascript

На странице имеется такой элемент. Как через js добавить к нему css?

```html
<div aria-expanded="true" data-modal="_dynamic_modal_0" class="v--modal-overlay scrollable">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получаем элемент, затем добавляем ему класс. Обратите внимание, что название примера класса во второй строчке кода указывается без точки.

```
const myModal = document.querySelector(".v--modal-overlay")
    
myModal.classList.add("class")
```

Второй вариант - inline css:

```
let myModal = document.querySelector(".v--modal-overlay")

myModal.style.marginBottom = '100px'
```

Обратите внимание на то, как записан параметр `marginBottom` . Именно таким образом нужно обращаться к параметрам стиля через JS.

Вот 3-й вариант, если хотите использовать привычную запись параметров css:

```
let myModal = document.querySelector(".v--modal-overlay")

myModal.style.cssText = `
color: red;
margin-bottom: 100px;
`
```

Здесь вы можете перечислить сразу несколько параметров в привычном для css синтаксисе. Обратите внимание на то, какие именно кавычки используются для записи.

Comment: Teslajke ясно. А к data-modal="_dynamic_modal_0" возможно обратится?

Comment: const myModal = document.querySelector('[data-modal="_dynamic_modal_0"]')

Comment: Teslajke, спасибо!